# Using Dict reader, how do I insert into CSV file?

Tags: python

I'm supposed to load a CSV file into the program memory, and when the user chooses option 1, they are allowed to add in a student's details. Upon pressing 'ENTER', the program will then write the user input into the csv file. I sort of got it to work, but if the user decides to add another user, it overides the first student details that's already in the CSV.

What I have so far is:

```
def insert_student():
    print()
    print("Insert a new student:")
    first_name = input("Enter first name:")
    last_name = input("Enter last name:")
    student_id = input("Enter student ID:")

    student_info = {"first_name":first_name,"last_name":last_name,"student_id":student_id}

    import csv
    filePath = "data.csv"        
    with open(filePath, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'student_id']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'first_name': first_name,
                         'last_name': last_name,
                         'student_id': student_id})
    print("New Student Record Inserted")
```

How do I make it such that when the user decides to add multiple student details, it doesn't override it, and adds it to a new row?

Comment: You need to open your file in append mode if you want to modify it more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in 'a' mode:

```
filePath = "data.csv" 
with open(filePath, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'student_id']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow({'first_name': first_name,
                     'last_name': last_name,
                     'student_id': student_id})
print("New Student Record Inserted")
```

Comment: It sort of works, but it keeps writing the header everytime there is a new entry. Any workaround?

Comment: Yeah take the fieldnames out of the loop. See edited answer. What you could do is write a small function to initiate the file and only write the headers when starting the script. There isn't really a better way, as in, all other ways are way more complicated.

Comment: Sorry if I keep asking, but I didn't want to completely remove the header haha. What I meant was, for the first entry, it prints out the header, and subsequent entries, it just fills in without the header.

Comment: You roughly have three options. 1) Open the file before you write to see if there are headers there. Then write headers if they are not there yet. This is terrible for performance, but hey, it works. 2) Write a file init function which you call once when the script starts. A bit hacky, but depending on your level of seriousness might be the easiest option. 3) Define an object and make the insert_student method a method of that object. Then you can keep a variable "headers_added" or something similar in object state. If you are serious, this is the best option. Your call.

Answer (score 0):

you have to open file with 'a' mode and write header only when it's new csv file,
try this:

```
import os
import csv

def insert_student():
    print()
    print("Insert a new student:")
    first_name = input("Enter first name:")
    last_name = input("Enter last name:")
    student_id = input("Enter student ID:")

    student_info = {"first_name": first_name, "last_name": last_name, "student_id": student_id}


    filePath = "data.csv"


    edit_mode = os.path.isfile(filePath)

    with open(filePath, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'student_id']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        if not edit_mode:
            writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'first_name': first_name,
                         'last_name': last_name,
                         'student_id': student_id})

    print("New Student Record Inserted")
```

Comment: It sort of works! But it didn't write the header. Any idea how to make it such that on the first entry, it writes the header, and on the subsequent entries, it doesn't? I tried checking if file size is = 0, and it doesn't work, because even when the file is empty, it's 1KB.